# Revtex4-1 with prl option doesn't show email address

Tags: mactex, revtex

I have a strange problem. I'm running latest MacTeX on Mountain Lion 10.8.2. When I compose an article using `revtex4-1` with `prl` as document class option, it doesn't display my email address while if I change `prl` to `pre`, it shows my email address. Does anyone has any idea, why this strange behaviour is occurring and how can I fix this. I'm pasting a snippet of the document preamble below

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,preprint,showpacs,amsmath]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\author{xyz}\email{xyz@xyz.com}
\title{Test}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I expanded your code to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and it compiles without errors here and displays also the email address. Maybe you use an outdated version of ``revtex4-1``. If you add the command ``\listfiles`` to your document preamble, the versions of all packages are exported to the log file. My ``revtex4-1`` version is ``4.1r``.

Comment: @BenediktBauer the OP said that the problem appears using the `prl` option, not `pre` as in your edit; using the former, the email won't show.

Comment: As @GonzaloMedina said it correctly, it's only a problem with `prl` option. I added `\listoffile` commands and the log file says that I have `4.1r` too. I compiled on my Mint distribution same file and it I could reproduce the same problem there as well. I don't understand what is the going on.

Comment: Well disabling `\usepackage{multibib}` did the trick.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible with an up-to-date TeX system, suggesting that an update is required.